# How to replace the initializer content of a global Array

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In LLVM IR, I have a global array of type `[4 x i32]`:

```
@data = local_unnamed_addr global [4 x i32] [i32 17, i32 31, i32 55, i32 7], align 4
```

Using a module pass, I want to modify the initializers of this array, in the original example `{17, 31, 55, 7}`.

I am able to detect the global data. `globalData` holds a reference to the `GlobalVariable`. Then I determine if it is initialized and an array type.

```
if(globalData.hasInitializer()) {
  auto arrayType = globalData.getInitializer()->getType();
  if(arrayType->isArrayTy()) {
    SmallVector<Constant *, 4> arrayContent(4); // How to get the dimension?
    // How to get each Constant from the orginal initializer?
    Constant* initializer = ConstantArray::get((ArrayType*) arrayType, arrayContent);
    globalData.setInitializer(initializer);
  }
}
```

However, I am missing how to get dimension of the array, the original integer initializers, and how to properly set the new initializer.

Right now, executing the showed code does not update the initializer array.

Comment: Did you look in the `SmallVector.h` file?

Comment: I am not sure about this because I don't have a setup in place to test this, but it is possible that the type that you get from ```globalData.getInitializer()->getType()``` might be a ```PointerType```.

Comment: And when you say that this does not update initializer, what are you expecting to happen? Because if I understand your code correctly, you are generating a new initializer array from the values of the original initializer and assigning it to the global, which will keep the same initial values for array members.